# How to set a Html 5 video starttime and endtime?

Tags: javascript, html, video

How to set a Html 5 video starttime and endtime?

I want to start and stop a html5 video at a certain time with the number keys.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $vid = document.getElementById("video1");
    $vid.width = $( window ).width();

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
var code = e.keyCode;

if(code == 49) {
    $vid.currentTime = 0;
    $vid.play();
    $vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
       if ($vid.currentTime >= 2) {
            $vid.pause();
        }
    }, false);
 }

if(code == 50) {
    $vid.currentTime = 2;
    $vid.play();
    $vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
       if ($vid.currentTime >= 4) {
            $vid.pause();
        }
    }, false);
}
});

});
```

This is my script so far..
I can go from code 50 to code 49 but not from 49 to 50!
How to fix this?

Comment: the problem is that you have two listeners added. I would make sure you either remove the previous listener before adding the next, or have a single listener that tracks both the most recently pressed keycode and reacts accordingly...

Comment: Thanks!
removeEventListener did it!
$vid.removeEventListener("timeupdate",time);